# Extracting Reduce results

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I'm solving a Diophantine equation inside of a function using `Reduce` but I'm having trouble extracting the necessary parts of the answer.

For example, if my input equation is linear, I get an output from `Reduce` like:

```
C[1] ∈ Integers && x == 8 + 49 C[1] && k == 1 + 5 C[1]
```

if the equation is a quadratic, though, I get:

```
(C[1] ∈ Integers && x == 20 - 49 C[1] && 
   k == 41 - 200 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && 
   x == 29 - 49 C[1] && k == 86 - 290 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2)
```

if the equation is cubic, I get:

```
C[1] ∈ 
  Integers && (x == 2 + 49 C[1] || x == 11 + 49 C[1] || 
   x == 36 + 49 C[1]) && k == 1/49 (9 + 5 x^3)
```

How do I identify and/or extract, say, the resulting condition on x? I originally used `Part` when I just had the linear case. So for example I would do something like:

```
Ans=Reduce[SomeEquality[x,k],{x,k},Integers];
X=x/.ToRules[Ans[[2]]/.{C[1]->0}]
```

But the outputs in the quadratic and cubic cases are in wildly different places...

Comment: The conditions you're getting at depend not only on `x`, but on the existence of another constants `C[i]`, which must be integers in your examples. You can't get rid of them if you want the full result set. There isn't "a condition on `x`" to extract. Sorry.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want in general, Aeryk, but *for these particular cases* would it be the output of `Last@Reap[(output of Reduce)/. {Equal[x, y_] :> Sow[y]}]`? This gives a list of all the "somethings" where the form `x==(something)` appears in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot test this in Mathematica right now, but pattern matching should work to get the bits that appear next to `x`. So for instance you could use

```
Cases[Ans,(x == z_)->(z/.C[1]->0),Infinity]
```

That will capture all the terms where x appears on the left of `==` and will give return what on the right side of that equality with `C[1]` replaced by 0.

Comment: Close, but to get to set C[1] to 0, it needs to be this way: `Cases[ans, (x == z_) -> (z), Infinity] /. C[1] -> 0`
And that's just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. I forgot that the syntax for `->` in ´Cases´ is rather rigid. Nesting ´/.´ and ´->´ will work in replacements though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to answer here because you cannot simply throw the condition of `Element[C[1], Integers]` away. At least you have to remember this and when your goal is to transform this result into a set of rules, then just throw the `Element` parts away and apply `ToRules`

```
(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == 20 - 49 C[1] && k == 41 - 200 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2) || 
(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == 29 - 49 C[1] && k == 86 - 290 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2) 
    /. HoldPattern[Element[__]] :> Sequence[]

{ToRules[%]}

(*
{{x -> 20 - 49 C[1], k -> 41 - 200 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2}, 
 {x -> 29 - 49 C[1], k -> 86 - 290 C[1] + 245 C[1]^2}}
*)
```